# How to use uniform_real_distribution to generate different numbers?

Tags: c++, random

I used default_random_engine to generate a list of different numbers, but they happen to be the same. I wonder to generate different numbers? I know srand() does. But can I use this default engine?

```
default_random_engine engine{ static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)) };
uniform_real_distribution<double>randomNumber{ 50,100 };
for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
  a[i]= randomNumber(engine);
  }
```

Comment: When you say they are all the same, do you mean all the numbers are the same in one run or that you get the same set of numbers each time?

Comment: Don't seed with `time(0)`, seed with `operator()` off a single instance of `std::random_device`, Either way, ideally seed only once for your entire process.

Comment: @PaulRooney Every time I generate a different array of random numbers. In this array, there happen to have same numbers(elements). I wonder how can I make every element in this array unique?

Comment: @JoviZhihaoZhou is *all* of this in some function you repeatedly call? If so, see the last sentence of my prior comment (stress the "once").

Comment: @WhozCraig do you mean "seed with operator() or a single instance"?

Comment: @JoviZhihaoZhou [I mean **both**](http://ideone.com/nW0gT2). The example linked only seeds the prng *once* for the entire process, using `operator()` from a single instance of `std::random_device`.

Comment: @WhozCraig got you thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior is by design for random number generators. You need to set the 'seed' for the random generator when you start your program.

If you have the C++ extensions @WhozGraig recommends they're best. It's very sloppy but many people use the time() function to get a different number each time the program runs.